# Bottom Navigation open camera

Tags: navigation, android

I am a developer and currently having an argument with PO regarding Bottom Navigation in Android. 
We have navigation bar with some basic functionality as described in [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html)

One of the tabs have *Take photo* functionality and PO want camera to open camera when clicking on that tab to avoid one extra click.

I am concerned about this idea, because:

- Navigation item can be clicked accidentally pretty often and open camera when user did not want it to open
- Opening camera is resource-intensive and might cause a problem where there is not much battery left on user's device
- It "detaches" user from current context - navigation view and opens another action in full screen.

Am I wrong? Is my PO right?

**EDIT**

I cannot provide a screenshot, but it is tab where you can scan something like QR code and observe result. It is not the core of app, but pretty important.

Regarding extra click - you have to navigate to that tab and press *Scan* button for the camera to open.

Comment: Could you please post an image of your current implementation? Also, what does your app do?

Answer (score 2):

If the most important functionality of your app is to take pictures, just like for example Instagram, I would say that the "Open Camera" button should be easy to click and prominent.

[image: Instagram]

As you can see in the image, Instagram places exactly in the middle of the bottom navigation bar.

If taking a picture is not an important functionality, then it should be less prominent.

Instagram does not open the camera immediately but first, takes you to the last taken images. Do you mean that by "one extra click"?